# Adding additional data fields when uploading file to Database w/ Django

Tags: python, django, upload, metadata, models

I'm new here and also new to Django and any kind of web development.
Right now, I am working on a project that allows users to submit academic papers to be edited by other users.
The problem I am having is that I would like to allow users to upload a file and with that file, upload some data about the file (meta data?) such as the title of the paper (listed as titleField) prompt, etc.
I have been able to find answers on how to only upload the file, but not on how to upload the data and the file as a whole package.

If anyone can shed any light on this, that would help me a lot!

Here is the models.py:

```
from django.db import models

class Document(models.Model):
    docfile = models.FileField(upload_to='documents/%Y/%m/%d')

    titleField = models.CharField(max_length=100, default="")

    dueDateField = models.IntegerField(default=10)

    classNumField = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    promptField = models.CharField(max_length=300, default="")
```

And below is the function that uploads the file. I understand how this section works, however it is uploading the additonal data from the forms that confuses me:

views.py

```
def list(request):
    # Handle file upload
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = DocumentForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            newdoc = Document(docfile = request.FILES['docfile'])
            newdoc.save()

            # Redirect to the document list after POST
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('ReadMyPaper.myapp.views.list'))
    else:
        form = DocumentForm() # A empty, unbound form

    # Load documents for the list page
    documents = Document.objects.all()

    # Render list page with the documents and the form
    return render_to_response(
        'myapp/list.html',
        {'documents': documents, 'form': form},
        context_instance=RequestContext(request)
    )
```

Comment: Can you also post the code for DocumentForm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using a ModelForm ? If no, thats how to create one:

```
# forms.py
from django import forms
from .models import Document

class DocumentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Document
```

And in both cases, how to properly use it:

```
# views.py

from .forms import DocumentForm


def document_list(request):
    # Handle file upload
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = DocumentForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            new_doc = form.save()

            # Redirect to the document list after POST
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('ReadMyPaper.myapp.views.list'))
    else:
        form = DocumentForm() # A empty, unbound form

    # Load documents for the list page
    documents = Document.objects.all()

    # Render list page with the documents and the form
    return render_to_response(
        'myapp/list.html',
        {'documents': documents, 'form': form},
        context_instance=RequestContext(request)
    )
```

First point : Django forms (the non-ModelForm ones) do two things:

1. they display their fields, and
2. they sanitize and validate their data.

So when using Djago forms, you shouldn't have to access `request.POST` (or `request.GET` in the rare cases you have a GET form) directly, only `form.cleaned_data`.

Second point: `ModelForm`s also know

1. how to create their own fields based on the associated model (but you can restrict / override these fields manually) and
2. create or update a model instance based on their (validated) data.

So when using a `ModelForm`, you shouldn't even have to do anything with the model itself in your view (for the most common use cases at least).

Comment: Thank you, Bruno! This was exactly what I needed. Now to make sure I understand properly, is what is happening that it takes all the data from the form and uploads in the database as one object? and I can access this Meta info correct? Thanks, again. This was really informative